# Add underline under the current tab button

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I created three buttons that correspond to three different tabs.

Is there a way to add an underline under the current tab button (under the red "zone")?

I basically intend to get something like mat-tab.

Can someone help me?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f4uvrl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Code**

```
 viewMode = 'tab1';

 <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap myrow">
    <a (click)="viewMode ='tab1';" class="btn" [class.activebtn1]="viewMode == 'tab1'" rel="tab1">TAB1 BUTTON
    </a>
    <a (click)="viewMode ='tab2'" class="btn" [class.activebtn]="viewMode == 'tab2'" rel="tab2">TAB2 BUTTON
    </a>
    <a (click)="viewMode ='tab3'" class="btn" [class.activebtn]="viewMode == 'tab3'" rel="tab3">TAB3 BUTTON
    </a>
  </div>

 <div [ngSwitch]="viewMode" style="margin-top:50px">
    <div id="tab1" *ngSwitchCase="'tab1'" [@slideInOut]>
   <span>TAB1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" *ngSwitchCase="'tab2'" [@slideInOut]>
       <span>TAB2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" *ngSwitchCase="'tab3'" [@slideInOut]>
        <span>TAB3</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example**

[image]

Comment: I believe a way to make them have an underline underneath it, is to add a link to the button. That is the easy, lazy way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/active-button-underline?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

---

You can use [pseudo-elements](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) to add the underline to the active button:

```css
.activebtn {
  /* This is set so that the ::before pseudo-element is absolutely 
     positioned relative to the button. */
  position: relative;
}

.activebtn::before {
  content: '';

  /* Absolutely positions the underline relative to the button. */
  position: absolute;

  /* This aligns the underline so that it is at the bottom of 
     the button. */
  bottom: 0;

  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. The problem here is that the underline just changes if the other button is clicked twice. Is there a way to just click on another button once time, the underline change to that button?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to use Angular so I can't tell you why it takes two clicks to get the underline to appear. Hopefully somebody can answer this question!

Comment: Solved ... the problem was this animation [@slideInOut] that was not even declared. It was enough to remove it and it was perfect! Thanks!